# Option to turn bluetooth on or Off is missing....it was present before

Tags: bluetooth

i have Hp Elitebook 8440p.....i can't find the option to turn bluetooth on and off....i have tried to find it every where but i can't.....
i know i have bluetooth available in my Laptop.....i have used it before but now i can't find the option to turn it On or Off...please help....[this is how it looks like in the Devices tab in settings...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj3NS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore it....I found it....Had to uninstall and delete the Bluetooth software.....refreshed...Old software got installed and the bluetooth option appeared at once.....It was problem with the Software....